# Laravel Application is downloading index.php instead of execution on MAMP

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5.5

I have a Laravel 5.5 application downloaded from hosting to localhost.

I am trying to run it on MAMP 4.2, PHP 7.1.9, Apache, but instead of being executed, it downloads this file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I have cleared the cache, and updated the compose.
I have other laravel apps on the same localhost, and they're working.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fixed it, by adding those two lines inside `/public/.htaccess` file:

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

Comment: Which tag in the .htaccess file did you add this?  <IfModule> ?

Comment: Outside of the <IfModule>

Comment: This is not working in my case